# How to use templates

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP site contain main menu and it has many pages so I wonder is there a way to write the main menu HTML in one file and just include this file once in each page ? this as you know will help me not to repeat update in each page when there are changes in the main menu.

Comment: This is a very common use for PHP, I would personally just search around for a PHP Template Engine or CMS, there are a ton of them out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier way is to put the menu HTML inside a menu.php file.

Then, wherever you want that menu to be included, just do:

```
<?php require 'menu.php'; ?>
```